# how to avoid singularity in numerical integration?

Tags: plot, integration, maple, expansion

I would like to plot `E2(t)` in Maple18, but it blows up around t=0. How can I apply the asymptotic evaluation for this integral to avoid the singularity and solve this problem?

```
restart: with(plots):
with(Student[NumericalAnalysis]):
g1:=(x,t)->(-sqrt(t)/(2*sqrt(Pi*r^3)))*(sin((r*(x-1)^(2)/(4*t))+(Pi/4))-sin((r*(x+1)^(2)/(4*t))+(Pi/4))):

g2:=(x,t)->int(g1(x,t),r=1..infinity);

g3:=(x,t) -> (diff(g2(x,t),t)):


g4:=(x,t) -> (diff(g2(x,t),x,x)):


g5:=(x,t) -> ((1/2)*(g3(x,t)^2+g4(x,t)^2)):


E2:=t->(int(g5(x,t),x=0..100)):

evalf(E2(0));
Error, (in g1) numeric exception: division by zero
evalf(E2(1));
Error, (in g3) invalid input: diff received 1, which is not valid for its 2nd argument
plot(E2(t),t=0..20);
```

Best regards,

Comment: I just answered this on MaplePrimes. It's annoying when people ask the same question on different forums at the same time.

Comment: Carl, just copy-paste your answer here.

Comment: @Carl thank you for your answer and sorry for this situation. It was a urgent question for me and I wanted to increase my chance to get answer.

Comment: @2che: Your lack of any response to my Answer on MaplePrimes is disturbing.

Comment: @lolmaus - Andrey Mikhaylov: Okay, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "avoid the singularity". Your function is singular at t=0, and there's no way to change that. Just don't try to evaluate it at 0.

Your other problem is caused by trying to differentiate with respect to a number. What you need to do is create the procedure **E2** with **unapply**. Then the differentiations will be done symbolically. Here's your code, essentially. I removed superfluous parentheses, the **(x,t)->**, and the unneeded package loading.

```
restart:
g1:= -sqrt(t/Pi/r^3)/2 * 
     (sin(r*(x-1)^2/4/t+Pi/4)-sin(r*(x+1)^2/4/t+Pi/4)):
g2:= int(g1, r= 1..infinity):
g3:= diff(g2,t):
g4:= diff(g2,x$2):
g5:= (g3^2+g4^2)/2:
```

And here's **E2**:

```
E2:= unapply(Int(g5, x= 0..100, epsilon= 1e-4, digits= 7), t):
```

Note the capital **I** in **Int**. This will avoid wasting time trying symbolic integration and will go directly to numeric integration when **evalf** is applied. The **epsilon** and **digits** arguments will decrease the precision and increase the speed. The precision will still be adequate for a plot. The plot command is

```
plot(E2, 0..20, numpoints= 50, labels= [t, ``]);
```

This will take two to three minutes. If you increase the **numpoints** for a more-accurate plot, the time will increase proportionally.